# Python append to system arguments - bad practice?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm parsing system arguments in my Python project using `sys.argv`. At some point i had to modify the script after having written the logic that parses system args. I added a line the basically appends a string to `sys.argv` so the logic that parses it won't be changed -

`sys.argv.append('some string here')`

Is it a bad practice to modify the system arguments after they have been created for the program ?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to do this to begin with, but one reason I can come up with to *not* do this would be creating a headache for future maintainers of your code. If someone later writes code to use the contents of `sys.argv` and the arguments actually passed do not match those, it may have unintended effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is bad  practice** to modify `sys.argv` in Python and it's equivalent in other languages.

In these situations I recommend a `parsed_args` variable which has all your parsed data from `sys.argv`, any default values that you would like to set, and any modifications that "middleware" would make.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but beware of `parsed_args = sys.argv` because modifying `parsed_args` then changes `sys.argv` as well.

Comment: @clemisch, I think @dotancohen means `parsed_args = sys.argv[:]` and not `parsed_args = sys.argv`. This way the list is duplicated and not aliased.

Comment: @clemisch, et al: In fact I personally set each `parsed_args` element explicitly, but you are correct in mentioning the warning.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion in such case it would be better to first parse those arguments using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

That way you can get `Namespace` object, that can be modified and much easier to maintain than hardcoding`sys.argv`.

After that you can modify `Namespace` any way you want

Small example:

```
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Description")
    parser.add_argument('--file_path')
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
    return parsed_args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    print(args.file_path) # the argument passed while running script
    args.another_value = "value"
    print(args.another_value) # value added within code
    setattr(args, 'yet_another', 'value') # another way to set attributes
```

Comment: Some of the features of argparse will end your program before you have a chance to do anything. Missing required options, bad types, and so on cause argparse to print its help message and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I like to leave the original command-line (argv) alone and work on a copy. That way, I can always see the original. Perhaps I want to compare what the user actually typed out with what I filled in later from environment variables, default values, or whatever. That's pretty handy while tracking down a problem.

Consider the case where you are using `argparse`. The particular library isn't important and this is a good practice for just about anything. Instead of relying on a default source, such as `sys.argv`, always supply it.

In this incomplete example, `main()` takes a list that you supply. That can be from `sys.argv` or whatever list you like. That's pretty handy for testing as you supply different lists to check various scenarios. This decoupling gives you quite a bit of flexibility:

```
def main(options):
    parsed_args = process_args(options)
    ... rest of program ...

def process_args(options):
    ...do stuff to fix up options, like enable things by env vars...
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
    parser.add_argument(...)
    parsed_args = parser.parse_args(options) # argument instead of default
    ...fix up parsed_args for whatever you want to add...
    return parsed_args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:]) # remember the program name is the first item
```

Magic or default variables are nice for quick and dirty things, but those generally constrain you too much for larger projects where consumers might want to do things you hadn't considered. Remember, [Pythonic code likes to be explicit rather than implicit](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) (yet, so many opportunities in core to be implicit!).